# An unusual trimmer resistor

Tags: resistors

[image: Trimmer resistor (?)]

I first thought that this component had failed from old age as its jacket was crumbling away. However the metal clamp attached to it about halfway down has a dimple presumably to make contact with the exposed coil, and has a wire heading off from it. My guess is it must be a type of trimmer resistor I haven't encountered before, where the clamp is snugged up once the appropriate value is found. Does this part have a reliable name? I'd like to look into them further.

For interest, I found it inside an old vacuum tube voltmeter that I'm being careful about before powering up.

Comment: I'd just call it "adjustable power resistor". I have a really huge one (more than 100W) in my collection of old parts.

Comment: An adjustable power resistor is called a [Rheostat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#Rheostat) ? Larger horizontal versions of these used to be present in the High school labs for use in experiments. The sliding part came with it's own scale so that we could know the ratio of lengths from each end.

Comment: @AJN:  In my mind, a rheostat should be easily adjustable by turning a knob.

Comment: @PeterBennett I would call this a rheostat too, personally.

Comment: If the results from an image search on Google are any yardstick,  rheostat is indeed the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjustable power resistor. [Here](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/res_210.pdf?r=false) is an example of a current production unit. [Here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/31850/ave.pdf) is another type.

The resolution is not very good on them, and the open element is not ideal, but they have their applications even today.

[image]

Comment: I know that they do still make these, but it feels so *weird* to see a picture of one of these old ceramic tube rheostats with "RoHS compliant" next to it.

Comment: @Hearth yes, a design that old you definitely expect to have lead and maybe asbestos in it.

Comment: Not just that, but also that I associate these with equipment that predates the RoHS directive, and I've never seen one used in anything modern enough for RoHS to have existed when it was made!

Answer (score 2):

These were common in vacuum tube electronics. They were referred to as a power resistor. I remember IRC as one brand and probably have a few around. Vacuum circuits consumed a lot more power (both voltage and current) then transistors and the components used had to be compatible. The one shown was set and cemented into place so it would not change adjustment. Tolerance of parts were not near as good as they are today. Just out of curiosity is that a Heath Kit or another do it yourself unit.

Comment: Specifically this is an old-fashioned rheostat, not just an ordinary resistor.

Comment: It's a commercial unit manufactured by University Instruments AKA University Graham in Australia (my home) in I believe the 1950s. I recently bought it from a long-retired TV and radio repair man aged 95. Some of the other gear I bought from was definitely kit construction but this VTVM was a production model.

Comment: @SimonOwen -- uh oh, now you'll have to explain to the kids what a VTVM is.

Comment: I'd love to, but until I understand it myself I think I'll just keep asking questions:)